# LINQ to SQL delete property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

I have a .dbml designer view, i have classes with properties, when i want to delete a property from a class, it deletes it from the view, but it is still possible to access that property from my code.

So my question is: How can i delete class property, that it wouldn't be accessable?

EDIT:

[image: class diagram]

View is something like that, and when i delete any property. It still is possible to access that property in my code. How can i delete that property permanently?

Comment: What you mean, delete a property? Do you want to set it to `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DBML is the input for a code generator. If the property doesn't exist in the input, it shouldn't exist in the generated output. I suspect you simply need to hit "save" on the DBML - or failing that, right click the DBML and hit "run custom tool".

If it *still* exists after that, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to see where it is being defined.

Comment: Saving the DBML file did not execute MSLinqToSQLGenerator for some reason, but "run custom tool" did the job. Thanks.